# Decompressing bytes in C#

Tags: javascript, python, c#, compression, cryptojs

I have a simple program which is decompressing a byte array in C#.
There is the code of "Decompress" func:

```
private byte[] Decompress(byte[] compressed)
        {
            using var from = new MemoryStream(compressed);
            using var to = new MemoryStream();
            using var gZipStream = new GZipStream(from, CompressionMode.Decompress);
            gZipStream.CopyTo(to);
            return to.ToArray();
        }
```

and I have two byte arrays

```
var first = new byte[] { 31, 139, 8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 10, 45, 202, 65, 10, 128, 48, 12, 5, 209, 171, 132, 28, 195, 219, 68, 251, 91, 11, 38, 41, 105, 92, 137, 119, 23, 197, 221, 240, 152, 139, 39, 80, 120, 185, 88, 13, 234, 214, 55, 94, 88, 197, 154, 83, 115, 73, 154, 103, 84, 217, 64, 56, 48, 118, 177, 164, 130, 57, 164, 7, 5, 20, 186, 226, 141, 22, 72, 90, 97, 168, 61, 41, 251, 167, 7, 124, 72, 20, 250, 167, 233, 145, 124, 223, 15, 199, 8, 21, 161, 110, 0, 0, 0 };

var second = new byte[] { 31, 139, 8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 10, 1, 80, 0, 175, 255, 34, 127, 33, 66, 194, 252, 100, 6, 77, 155, 56, 146, 208, 225, 255, 219, 203, 33, 122, 153, 14, 246, 130, 28, 163, 183, 127, 145, 96, 71, 208, 206, 123, 9, 122, 133, 204, 255, 86, 191, 73, 197, 91, 247, 121, 156, 180, 101, 176, 125, 158, 123, 114, 192, 252, 70, 193, 148, 180, 183, 200, 146, 79, 121, 135, 152, 90, 247, 107, 168, 157, 128, 84, 121, 4, 122, 92, 145, 45, 223, 177, 179, 189, 149, 80, 0, 0, 0 }
```

my next step is:

```
var decompressed = Decompress(first);
var result = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(decompressed);

Output: {"seed":{"mnemonic":"mango goat surface elephant despair remember regret benefit timber leopard member sort"}}
```

```
var decompressed = Decompress(second);
var result = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(decompressed);

Output: "!B??d♠M?8??????!z???∟???`G??{  z???V?I?[?y??e?}?{r??F?????Oy??Z?k???Ty♦z\?-?
```

The structure of these arrays is the same... length (103), first 10 elements and last 3 elements. But first array decompresses with func Decompress fine and the second one is very bad. I don't know why it's happening. Someone explain where is my mistake.

I tried to decompress with python using gzip but I have the same result. There is the code

```
import gzip

first = [31, 139, 8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 10, 45, 202, 65, 10, 128, 48, 12, 5, 209, 171, 132, 28, 195, 219, 68, 251, 91, 11, 38, 41, 105, 92, 137, 119, 23, 197, 221, 240, 152, 139, 39, 80, 120, 185, 88, 13, 234, 214, 55, 94, 88, 197, 154, 83, 115, 73, 154, 103, 84, 217, 64, 56, 48, 118, 177, 164, 130, 57, 164, 7, 5, 20, 186, 226, 141, 22, 72, 90, 97, 168, 61, 41, 251, 167, 7, 124, 72, 20, 250, 167, 233, 145, 124, 223, 15, 199, 8, 21, 161, 110, 0, 0, 0 ];

second = [31, 139, 8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 10, 1, 80, 0, 175, 255, 34, 127, 33, 66, 194, 252, 100, 6, 77, 155, 56, 146, 208, 225, 255, 219, 203, 33, 122, 153, 14, 246, 130, 28, 163, 183, 127, 145, 96, 71, 208, 206, 123, 9, 122, 133, 204, 255, 86, 191, 73, 197, 91, 247, 121, 156, 180, 101, 176, 125, 158, 123, 114, 192, 252, 70, 193, 148, 180, 183, 200, 146, 79, 121, 135, 152, 90, 247, 107, 168, 157, 128, 84, 121, 4, 122, 92, 145, 45, 223, 177, 179, 189, 149, 80, 0, 0, 0 ];

bytes_of_values = bytes(first)
decompressed_block = gzip.decompress(bytes_of_values)
print(decompressed_block.decode('utf8', 'ignore'))
#Output: {"seed":{"mnemonic":"mango goat surface elephant despair remember regret benefit timber leopard member sort"}}

bytes_of_values = bytes(second)
decompressed_block = gzip.decompress(bytes_of_values)
print(decompressed_block.decode('utf8', 'ignore'))
#Output: "!Bd♠M8!z∟`G{   zVI[ye}{rFȒOyZkTy♦z\-
```

UPDATE #1
**FIRST ARRAY** was expanded with this JS function.

```
const crypto = require('crypto')

module.exports = function (size        )         {
  return {
    expand (data        )         {
      const buffer = crypto.randomBytes(data.length < size - 4 ? size : data.length + 4)
      buffer.writeUInt32BE(data.length, 0)
      data.copy(buffer, 4, 0)
      return buffer
    },
    shrink (buffer        )         {
      const dataLen = buffer.readUInt32BE(0)
      return buffer.slice(4, dataLen + 4)
    }
  }
}
```

Where **size** = 2 ** 15 (2^15 = 32768); data = {"seed":{"mnemonic":"mango goat surface elephant despair remember regret benefit timber leopard member sort"}}. In output we have a Buffer with size 32768. After that I take this Buffer and convert to string like "[1, 2, 3 ,4 ,5, etc.]" (remind that size is 32768) and pass this to C#. In C# I use this code:

```
var shrink = BinaryPrimitives.ReadUInt32BigEndian(data); //data == array with size 32768 (string from JS)
//shrink == 103 (integer)
var segment = new ArraySegment<byte>(data, 4, (int)shrink).ToArray();
// segment == FIRST ARRAY
```

after following these steps I get the **FIRST ARRAY** and it decompresses fine. The structure of the first array are identical to **SECOND ARRAY**. And I understood that SECOND ARRAY uses the same algorithm. But it doesn't unpack.

Comment: So it seems the second byte array was compressed uning a different algorithm. Where did you get it from?

Comment: The header data `31, 139, 8, 0, 0, 0, 0` does indicate that this is indeed using GZipStream compression. In that case, the data would appear to not actually be a string. Where did it come from?

Comment: Maybe its correct? Without knowing what should be correct (what was and how it was compressed) we can't really help.

Comment: updated with adding additional code from compressing with JS

Comment: @MatthewWatson if "not actually be a string" than why first array decompressing fine?

Comment: i'm redy to try any method which one do you recommend. Second array is 100% must be a string like output after decompressing from first array

Comment: @PineappleHaze The second one is not actually a string. The first one obviously is.

Comment: @MatthewWatson what is can be second array?

Comment: No idea - how was it created?

Comment: @MatthewWatson It is created just like the first one array, with using js code wich i added in UPDATE #1. Maybe some parameters can be different, in second array?

Comment: @MatthewWatson btw output in second array contains '{' and '}'. So i guess it's JSON 100%. See: !B??d♠M?8??????!z???∟???`G??{  z???V?I?[?y??e?}?{r??F?????Oy??Z?k???Ty♦z\?-?

Comment: @MatthewWatson maybe encoding is not UTF8? how can i check it if this approach is real

Comment: I tried it with various encodings, but I couldn't find any that worked. I'm afraid I don't have enough information to do any more.